# How do I return list with specific properties using the map method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a list of objects that looks like this and using map I want to return three of the properties. In the below list of objects I want to use map to return id, name and estimated_diameter. How do I do this? Is this possible with the map method? The following function returns a list of undefined objects.

```
const listOfObjects.map(o => {
  return o.id && o.name && o.estimated_diamer;
});
console.log(listOfObjects); // returns [undefined, undefined, ...]
```

The above returns [undefined, undefined, ...]

List of object:

```
[
  {
    links: {
      self: 'http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/3720769?api_key=DEMO_KEY'
    },
    id: '3720769',
    neo_reference_id: '3720769',
    name: '(2015 KH157)',
    nasa_jpl_url: 'http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3720769',
    absolute_magnitude_h: 19.9,
    estimated_diameter: {
      kilometers: [Object],
      meters: [Object],
      miles: [Object],
      feet: [Object]
    },
    is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid: true,
    close_approach_data: [ [Object] ],
    is_sentry_object: false
  },
  {
    links: {
      self: 'http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/2152561?api_key=DEMO_KEY'
    },
    id: '2152561',
    neo_reference_id: '2152561',
    name: '152561 (1991 RB)',
    nasa_jpl_url: 'http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=2152561',
    absolute_magnitude_h: 19,
    estimated_diameter: {
      kilometers: [Object],
      meters: [Object],
      miles: [Object],
      feet: [Object]
    },
    is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid: true,
    close_approach_data: [ [Object] ],
    is_sentry_object: false
  },
  {
    links: {
      self: 'http://www.neowsapp.com/rest/v1/neo/3441171?api_key=DEMO_KEY'
    },
    id: '3441171',
    neo_reference_id: '3441171',
    name: '(2008 XW2)',
    nasa_jpl_url: 'http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi?sstr=3441171',
    absolute_magnitude_h: 20.7,
    estimated_diameter: {
      kilometers: [Object],
      meters: [Object],
      miles: [Object],
      feet: [Object]
    },
    is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid: true,
    close_approach_data: [ [Object] ],
    is_sentry_object: false
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: `return { id: o.id, name: o.name, estimated_diamer: o.estimated_diamer };`

Comment: Or: `{ id, name, estimated_diamer } = o;` then `return { id, name, estimated_diamer };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a new object with only the values you are looking for:

```
const listOfObjects.map(o => {
  return { id: o.id, name: o.name, estimated_diamer: o.estimated_diamer };
});
```